# Having an Issue with too many parameters being passed to stored procedures in ColdFusion 2016

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have several stored procedures in an application that were functioning perfectly (for years) until our recent upgrade from ColdFusion 2010 to ColdFusion 2016.  Now, I am getting error messages of either too many parameters or a certain parameter is not a parameter is not contained in the procedure that is being called.

I have opted to upload some code so people can better understand what is actually happening. Still learning how to format code here so please forgive me if it is still lacking.

In both cases I have double checked the parameter lists in the stored procedure in the procedure calls and have found that they are all indeed correct. In fact, nothing has changed in this code for over 5 years. This behavior has only begun since the upgrade has taken place.

Below is the first example.  I will list the procedure call (in cfscript) 
first then the parameter list from the stored procedure and then the error message it produced:

```
public query function readStorage(numeric group1=0,numeric group2=0) {  
     local.group1Value = arguments.group1?arguments.group1:"";  
     local.group2Value = arguments.group2?arguments.group2:"";  
     spService = new storedproc();   
     spService.setDatasource(variables.dsn);  
     spService.setUsername(variables.userName);  
     spService.setPassword(variables.password);   
     spService.setProcedure("usp_readCompatibilityStorage");
     spService.addParam(dbvarname="@group1Id",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
           , type="in",value=local.group1Value,null=!arguments.group1);  
     spService.addParam(dbvarname="@group2Id",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
          ,type="in",value=local.group2Value,null=!arguments.group2);  
     spService.addProcResult(name="rs1",resultset=1);  

     local.result = spService.execute();   

     return local.result.getProcResultSets().rs1;   
}
```

Below is the parameter list from the stored procedure:

```
 @groupId1  int = NULL        
,@groupId2  int = NULL
```

Below is the error message I get:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]@group1Id is not a
>   parameter for procedure usp_readCompatibilityStorage.

Second Example:

```
public query function read(string cribIdList="",  
                        numeric cribNumber=0,  
                        string isAnnex="",  
                        numeric siteId=0,  
                        string parentCribIdList="",  
                        numeric supervisorId=0,  
                        numeric statusId=0,  
                        string orderBy="cribNumber ASC") {  

    local.cribNumberValue = arguments.cribNumber?arguments.cribNumber:"";  
    local.siteIdValue = arguments.siteId?arguments.siteId:"";  
    local.superIdValue = arguments.supervisorId ? arguments.supervisorId:"";  
    local.statusIdValue = arguments.statusId ? arguments.statusId:"";  

    spService = new storedproc();   
    spService.setDatasource(variables.dsn);  
    spService.setUsername(variables.userName);  
    spService.setPassword(variables.password);   
    spService.setProcedure("usp_readCrib");   

    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@cribIdList",cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
        ,type="in",value=arguments.cribIdList
        ,null=!len(arguments.cribIdList));  
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@cribNumber",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
         ,type="in",value=local.cribNumberValue
         ,null=!arguments.cribNumber);   
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@isAnnex",cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
        ,type="in",value=arguments.isAnnex,null=!len(arguments.isAnnex));  
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@siteId",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"
         ,type="in",value=local.siteIdValue,null=!arguments.siteId);  
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@parentCribIdList" 
         , cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", type="in"
         , value=arguments.parentCribIdList
         , null=!len(arguments.parentCribIdList));  
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@supervisorId", 
         cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer", type="in",value=local.superIdValue
         , null=!arguments.supervisorId);  
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@statusId"
         , cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer", type="in"
         , value=local.statusIdValue, null=!arguments.statusId);        
    spService.addParam(dbvarname="@orderBy",cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
         , type="in",value=arguments.orderBy);  
    spService.addProcResult(name="rs1",resultset=1);  

    local.result = spService.execute();  

    return local.result.getProcResultSets().rs1;   
}
```

Below is the parameter list from the stored procedure:

```
@cribIdList         varchar(500) = NULL  
,@cribNumber        int = NULL  
,@isAnnex           varchar(3) = NULL  
,@siteId            int = NULL  
,@parentCribIdList  varchar(500) = NULL  
,@supervisorId      int = NULL  
,@statusId          int = NULL  
,@orderBy           varchar(50)
```

Below is the message returned from the server:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Procedure or function
>   usp_readCrib has too many arguments specified.

In the case of both errors, they seem to be occurring at the following path:

`````
Error Details - struct
COLUMN      0
ID          CFSTOREDPROC
LINE        489
RAW_TRACE   at cfbase2ecfc235349229$funcINVOKETAG.runFunction(E:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion\base.cfc:489)
TEMPLATE    E:    \ColdFusion2016\cfusion\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion\base.cfc
TYPE    CFML````
`````

Comment: Upgraded from what version? Hard to say without seeing any code. Could you put together a small demo proc and code that shows the issue, or post a sample of the code on gist, if it's too long for S.O.? Without knowing more, I will say we ran into problems with a legacy app when upgrading from 10 to 2016. Unbeknownst to us, the legacy code had some wrong @dbvarname variables. It wasn't an issue in CF10 because that parameter was ignored. Along comes CF11, where Adobe resurrects `dbvarname` and the code started throwing all kinds of errors until we corrected the parameter names.

Comment: .. silly question but are you 100% sure the parameters all match, that you're calling the correct stored procedures - AND hitting the correct database? Reason for asking is because those look like SQL Server error messages. You'd get the same error from EXEC if you misspelled a parameter name, or supplied too many: `EXEC myProc @wrongParamName=123`

Comment: With the first procedure, the parameter names don't match. The CF code uses  `@group1Id` ("1" in the middle) - but the procedure uses ` @groupId1` ("1" at the end)

Comment: The second procedure works fine under CF2016 and 2018. Are you sure those are the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion 10 and greater limit the amount of parameters in a request to 100 by default. Fortunately this can be updated and changed to reflect the required amount of parameters you need for your stored procedures.

[image: Screen shot of ColdFusion Administrator]

Comment: [Stored procedure parameters](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprocparam.html) are different than POST parameters

Comment: @Ageax He notes the calls are in CF Script which is potentially wrapped in a function that could be called from a post from a CFM. this is why I tossed this one out there.

Comment: Yes, it's a good guess, but the POST limit is applied before the target script is executed. If too many parameters are found, the request is aborted before any CFML code can execute. Since the error is clearly caused by CFML code, that means the request made it past the POST filter and the issue is something else.